# How to remove milliseconds in datetime python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I want to print the amount of days, hours, minutes and seconds until christmas day but when it prints, it also gives me the millisecond. I tried doing `print(remain_until_xmas.strip(.)` but that didn't work. Here is the code

```
import datetime as dt

xmas = dt.datetime(2020, 12, 25)
now = dt.datetime.now()
until_xmas = xmas - now

print(until_xmas)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the time live, you can use this code:

```py
import time
time = str(time.strftime("%M")) + ":" + str(time.strftime("%S"))
print(time)
```

This will give you the current time in Minutes and Seconds, and if you put it in a loop, it will keep updating itself.

If you want the day and month, you can use

```py
print(time.strftime("%A, %B %e")) -
```

With this code, you can then subtract the Xmas date from the current date, and retrieve what you want.

This would be your final code:

```py
import time
month = time.strftime("%m")
day = time.strftime("%d")
hour = time.strftime("%H")
minute = time.strftime("%M")
second = time.strftime("%S")
chrmonth = 12
chrday = 23
chrhour = 12
chrminute = 60
chrsecond = 60
print("The time until christmas is, ", int(chrmonth) - int(month), "months", int(chrday) - int(day), "days", int(chrhour) - int(hour), "hours", int(chrminute) - int(minute), "minutes", int(chrsecond) - int(second), "seconds")
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Is there any way of doing it with datetime or do I have to use time? If I have to use time, could you rework my code to be in time please :). I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok, no problem!

Comment: Thank you so much, you are a legend!

Comment: Super sorry, I didn't see this until now. I have upvoted your answer :).

Answer (score -1):

you can use `.strftime()`

`print(until_xmas.strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))`

see more [here about strftime](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime).

Comment: There is no until_xmas attribute for ```strftime()```.